# Buefy / Bulma: contenteditable div crashes Safari

Tags: contenteditable, bulma, buefy

When you create a contentEditable div, include the Buefy/Bulma stylesheet, open the web page in Safari, place your cursor in the editable div, and try to enter text, Safari freezes.

HTML that triggers the error:

```
<div contentEditable="true"></div>
```

I'm using Safari v13.0.3 and Buefy v0.8.8.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a bug in WebKit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202262

Using a contenteditable div, when text-rendering is set to `optimizeLegibility` and font-family includes `-apple-system`, the bug is triggered. This text-rendering and font-family combination is used by Buefy / Bulma. From the stylesheet:

```
html {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  min-width: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

...

body,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}
```

The fix is to override font-family for the editable div. I include the fonts from Bulma's stylesheet, **except** `-apple-system`, and Safari doesn't crash:

```
<div contentEditable="true"
  style="font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;"></div>
```